# Multiplicity constraint violated error while implementing chat functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am implementing [Chat functionality](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails) excatly like this one in asp.net.This is the model explaination  [image: Model is like this]

My classes are: User, Conversaiton and Message:

```
public class User
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }       
    //keys       
    public ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
}
public class Conversation
{        
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public User RecipientUser { get; set; }
    public Guid SenderUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

and finally,

```
public class Message
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelivered { get; set; }
    public bool IsSeen { get; set; }
    public Guid SenderUserId { get; set; }
    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using EntityTypeConfiguration using fluent Api which are:

```
public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Conversations).WithRequired(x => x.RecipientUser).HasForeignKey(x => x.SenderUserId);
    }
}
 public class ConversationConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Conversation>
{
    public ConversationConfig()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        HasRequired(x => x.RecipientUser).WithMany(x => x.Conversations);
        HasMany(x => x.Messages).WithRequired(x => x.Conversation).HasForeignKey(x => x.SenderUserId);           
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error as follows: 
**Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Conversation_RecipientUser_Target' of the relationship 'DataAcessLayer.Conversation_RecipientUser' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.**

If anyone could help  me. Many thanks!!!

Comment: your code looking ok? can you please write an example for how you are using them or how you are joining the data.

Comment: `var conversation = new Conversation();`
    `conversation.Messages.Add(message);`
    `conversation.RecipientUser = user;`
    `currentUser.Conversations.Add(conversation);` This is the way i am joining my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the exception when I used your model, but that doesn't matter much, because you've got to make some changes anyway.

First, this configuration in `UserConfig` ...

```
HasMany(x => x.Conversations).WithRequired(x => x.RecipientUser)
              .HasForeignKey(x => x.SenderUserId);
```

... doesn't make sense to me. This means that the conversations belong to the recipient, not to the sender, which in itself is somewhat unexpected. But the name of the foreign key is `SenderUserId`. If you save objects into this model, `SenderUserId` will get the value of the recipient's `ID`!

Second, assuming the previous point was an error, you make it harder than necessary by defining ...

```
public User RecipientUser { get; set; }
public Guid SenderUserId { get; set; }
```

This means that you can only navigate from `Conversation` to the sender `User` by an explicit join over `SenderUserId`. Conversely, you can only set the recipient by setting `RecipientUser`, not by simply setting a foreign key value.

Third, you shouldn't have this `SenderUserId` in `Message`. It should be `ConversationId` instead. You can find a `Message`'s sender through the `Conversation` it belongs to.

All in all, I changed your model into this, reducing it to the bare-bone minimum, and using `int` for `ID`, just because it's easier reading:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
}

public class Conversation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SenderUserID { get; set; }
    public User SenderUser { get; set;}
    public int RecipientUserID { get; set; }
    public User RecipientUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int ConversationID { get; set; }
    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
}
```

And the only configuration:

```
public class ConversationConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Conversation>
{
    public ConversationConfig()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.ID);
        HasRequired(c => c.SenderUser).WithMany(u => u.Conversations)
                          .HasForeignKey(c => c.SenderUserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        HasRequired(c => c.RecipientUser).WithMany()
                          .HasForeignKey(c => c.RecipientUserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasMany(c => c.Messages).WithRequired(x => x.Conversation)
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.ConversationID);
    }
}
```

(One of the foreign keys doesn't have cascaded delete because that will cause a SQL-Server error: multiple cascade paths).

A simple test:

```
using (DbContext db = new DbContext(connectionString))
{
    var send = new User { Name = "Sender" };
    db.Set<User>().Add(send);

    var rec = new User { Name = "Recipient" };
    var messages = new[] { new Message { Text = "a" }, new Message { Text = "b" } };
    var conv = new Conversation { SenderUser = send, RecipientUser = rec, Messages = messages };

    db.Set<User>().Add(rec);
    db.Set<Conversation>().Add(conv);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Result:

Users:

```sql
ID    Name
1     Recipient
2     Sender
```

Converstions:

```sql
ID    RecipientUserID    SenderUserID
11    1                  2
```

Messages:

```sql
ID    Text    ConversationID
21    a       11
22    b       11
```

Comment: Thank you Sir.. It works great. Also I had to add `public User SenderUser {get;set;}` in Conversation class. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given Conversation has 1 User foreign key-column which called SenderUserId

```
    // Here you set the user key for the old user! 
    conversation.RecipientUser = user;

    // Here you are trying to change Conversation.SenderUserId from other user (currentUser)
    currentUser.Conversations.Add(conversation);
```

As you seen the added user into collection is not the same which you have assigned to the Conversation 1..n can not be working in this way correctly.

EF try to say to you with the exception, that you are trying to add/change more then entity for the releshinship one-to-zero-or-one, the error message is a little bit foggy I would say the error message should be like "One-to-many navigation properties should using the same entity"

**solution 1)**

```
    //  conversation.RecipientUser = user; remove this line why you need it?!
```

**solution 2)**

Create a new property in conversation one for CurrentUser and the other one for User

---

```
public class User
{
  public User()
  {
   Conversations = new List<Conversation>();
   CurrentUserConversations = new List<Conversation>();
   }

   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Conversation> CurrentUserConversations { get; set; }
}

public class Conversation
{
 public Conversation()
 {
  Messages = new List<Message>();
 }
 public Guid ID { get; set; }
 public User RecipientUser { get; set; }
 public Guid SenderUserId { get; set; }
 public User CurrentUser { get; set; }
 public Guid? CurrentUserId { get; set; }
 public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
 public UserConfig()
 {
  HasMany(x => x.Conversations).WithRequired(x => x.RecipientUser).HasForeignKey(x => x.SenderUserId);
  HasMany(x => x.CurrentUserConversations).WithOptional(x => x.CurrentUser).HasForeignKey(x => x.CurrentUserId);
 }
}
```

How to use it:

```
var user = myDbContext.Users.First();

var currentUser = new User { Active = true, Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
myDbContext.Users.Add(currentUser);

var message = new Message { IsDelivered = true };

var conversation = new Conversation() { ID = Guid.NewGuid() };
conversation.Messages.Add(message);

conversation.CurrentUser = user;
currentUser.Conversations.Add(conversation);

myDbContext.Conversations.Add(conversation);
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Created on user for CurrentUser and other one for RecipientUser  but still getting the same error. how should I tell EF explicitly what user i need to assign foreign constraint.? Also, It is a conversation between two  users: Current User and Recipient User. Thanks

Comment: I have addded, according to your code, these lines: `public ICollection<Conversation> CurrentUserConversations { get; set; }` `myDbContext.Conversations.Add(conversation);` Why do i need to add `myDbContext.Conversations.Add(conversation);`?  As it's a chat applciation, how do query conversation between two user say:  anotherUser and me. if anotherUser has messaged me first?

Comment: @AjayVerma that was a just code example. you have a stored current user   with the other user Conversation and each time current user get a new Conversation a new Conversation Id will be added to the database so you can search for Conversations.Select(c => currentUserId==currentUser.Id);  and the find the corresponder

Comment: following each one of your step but still getting **Multiplicity constraint violated.** error.

Comment: @AjayVerma sorry I want to help you but i do not have your code. Read about Inverse property in this link you will find a good tutorial , this will help you to understand the problem http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx  and read this link 2 http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx the soultion is done wtih code-first and your soultion is fleunt API but the concept is the same

Comment: Thank You Sir, I appreciate your effort

Comment: I am only trying to implement this [Demo](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails) on my website. Please check once and you can tell me if my model was correct?

Comment: there are many ways to do that but your Conversation can store 2 users one for send and one for receive or just the one user the receiver and one id the sender by the way Guid is not a good idea to use it as id

Comment: Hi. it's still in development mode so I'll surely change Guid to long or int. If there's any other way to implement normal messaging which can be later extend to chat, I am all ears. Can you please name one of those?